# PyQt5, Python, Qt Designer

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer

Делаю простой интерфейс к моему коду, использую *Qt Designer* + *PyQt5*,  столкнулся с такой ошибкой, что при попытке связать введённые данные в поле  виджета `LineEdit` с переменными кода выдаётся такая ошибка:

> Process finished with exit code -1073740791

Сам интерфейс довольно простой поля для ввода данных в виде виджетов `LineEdit` и кнопка при нажатии которой запускается программа на *Python*, выполняет расчёт и записывает результат. Но всё зависает как раз при нажатии данной кнопки, если убрать импорт `LineEdit` и просто жать кнопку, то она успешно открывает и запускает код в *PyCharm*.

Никак не могу понять проблема в самом коде или в чём-то ещё. Пример условного кода ниже. Буду очень благодарен за помощь. Заранее извиняюсь за формат, нет возможности скопировать и вставить.

```
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets

Form, _ = uic.loadUiType("1.ui") 


class Ui(QtWidgets.QDialog, Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__() 
        self.setupUi(self) 
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.ResultButtonPressed) 

    def ResultButtonPressed(self):
        file = open("Results.txt", "w") 
        a = float(self.lineEdit_1.text()) 
        b = int(self.lineEdit_2.text())
        # В переменную c из поля lineEdit_3
        # вводится несколько значений через пробел 
        # и из них формируется список
        c = [int(i) for i in self.lineEdit_3.text().split()]
        v = a + b 
        print(c, file=file) 
        print("Результаты: " + str(v), file=file)
        file.close() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Ui() 
    w.show() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Почему вы не приняли решение по предыдущему вопросу?

Comment: При решении из прошлого вопроса появляется ошибка, указанная выше, корректно будет по ней сделать отдельный вопрос

Comment: Вы спросили `Как получить текст из виджетов в PyQt5?` - вам ПРАВИЛЬНО ответили `self.lineEdit_1.text()`. То что у вас не сработало - это уже другая проблема и другой вопрос. Примите решение по предыдущему вопросу.

Comment: Так я принял решение по прошлому вопросу и создал новый вопрос с тем, с чем может быть связана данная ошибка

Comment: Arti, ok. Пожалуйста прочитайте еще раз, то что я вам писал в предыдущем вопросе (последние ДВА предложения), последнее предложение прочитайте три раза.

Comment: Я пробовал запускать и через консоль и через cmd и даже дебаггером  PyCharm, ошибка одна и та же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не предоставили минимальный воспроизводимый пример 
и не понятно как вы делали `1.ui`.

Если делать все правильно, то ваше приложение — работает.

**q1474262.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>289</width>
    <height>280</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <layout class="QFormLayout" name="formLayout">
     <property name="topMargin">
      <number>10</number>
     </property>
     <property name="rightMargin">
      <number>10</number>
     </property>
     <item row="0" column="0">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>40</width>
         <height>0</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>12</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>a</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="1">
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_1"/>
     </item>
     <item row="1" column="0">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>40</width>
         <height>0</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>12</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>b</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="1" column="1">
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_2"/>
     </item>
     <item row="2" column="0">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>40</width>
         <height>0</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>12</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>c</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="2" column="1">
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_3"/>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
   <item row="1" column="0">
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
     <property name="text">
      <string>PushButton</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets

Form, _ = uic.loadUiType("q1474262.ui") 
print(f'{Form} --- {_}')


class Ui(QtWidgets.QDialog, Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__() 
        self.setupUi(self) 
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.ResultButtonPressed) 

    def ResultButtonPressed(self):
        file = open("Results.txt", "w") 
        a = float(self.lineEdit_1.text()) 
        b = int(self.lineEdit_2.text())
        # В переменную c из поля lineEdit_3
        # вводится несколько значений через пробел 
        # и из них формируется список
        c = [int(i) for i in self.lineEdit_3.text().split()]
        v = a + b 
        print(c, file=file) 
        print("Результаты: " + str(v), file=file)
        file.close() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Ui() 
    w.show() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, если код составлен верно, значит проблема уже локальная, буду разбираться в данной тематике, на похожих вопросах писали, что может быть проблема с антивирусом и его влиянием. Вопрос закрываю, ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: Единственное, я в переменную c  передаю несколько значений, введённых через пробел, где из них формируется список, но это вряд ли сильно влияет на ситуацию

Comment: @Arti поставьте перед и после создания объекта `с` принты и вы поймете в той ли строке ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, если судить по дебаггеру, то код отрабатывает полностью, но вот именно вывода результатов почему-то нет, покопаюсь в антивирусе, переустановлю модуль pyqt5, а там уже будет видно. Ещё раз спасибо за проверку.

Comment: Решить проблему помог доваленный ```print()``` в самом конце кода после блока ```if __name__=="__main"```